Can we integrate Anylogic User Interface to Unity such that we can view the ui in realtime in ipad?
In Unity, I have a project that includes a scene featuring multiple televisions. My goal is to showcase data analysis of the factory and display it on these TVs. Additionally, the project should be compatible with iPad, and any user interface logic should be displayed seamlessly.
I attempted to integrate Any Logic but couldn't find an API to link it with Unity. Could you verify and suggest alternatives if possible?

we did the connection between AnyLogic and Unity last year and there are some papers that you can find who do it again. But there's no API and it's also very hard if not impossible to do something reusable.
What you can do is:

Export all the coordinates of all the objects of interest from AnyLogic and create a Unity project from scratch and play it like a video showing the objects of interest

If you want for the AnyLogic model to be connected directly to Unity and show in real time, you will still need to create all the environment in Unity from scratch and communicate between AnyLogic and Unity using UDP or TCP/IP sending the position of the objects using JSON for instance


Problems: Unity has its own physical properties, so the movements between AnyLogic and Unity will never be exact... For instance in unity a person will move its legs so you need to adjust the behavior of that character depending on the speed, which is something you don't do in AnYLogic... Also something not obvious is how a resource interacts with agents, in AnyLogic there's teleportation, and sometimes Unity doesn't understand that.
There are lots of problems you encounter, as if there is no real time compatibility.
But if you think about it, if you want to do a simulation in Unity directly, you can. No need to use AnYLogic

Hi Felipe, we are creating a what if scenario for the product is there any other alternatives to Any Logic?
